# Netsuite Saved Search for List of Message and their respective File attachment

Tags: netsuite, message, suitetalk, saved-searches

I have an use case to generate a report to get the list of message ID and their respective file ID (attachment). The report should show all message and the respective attachment attached to the message.

Currently I have some third parties software which connected to NS schema and replicated the entire schema in my SQL database. Below are the schema that I have replicated, however, I cannot find the linkage / joining for the relevant tables to link up message and file.

- SuiteTalk (Browser Schema)
- SuiteAnalytics via ODBC (Connect Schema)
- SuiteAnlaytics via netsuite2.com (Record Catalogue)

I have also tried to generate via Saved Search, which I started with message : Internal ID as the base and tried to include the file ID as the additional column as part of the search result. However, I cannot find any file relevant field for it. I am not sure if this saved search is even possible.

Kindly check with all experts here, if there is alternative or modification of the saved search to achieve the desired result. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a saved search with a Type of "Message", you can add a column (results tab) for the field "Attachments : Internal ID".